# Unable to pass Date object to back end from React to Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm having issues with getting my back end to accept the value that is passed from the value that is returned from the date picker component I'm using for my front end. I'm using Calendar from react-calendar library. I did console.log() to see what format was being stored as the date, and used Postman to try a POST request with that date. I'm trying to add an object that looks like this:

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "customer": "Wal Mart",
        "destination": "Chicago,IL",
        "driver": "Jeff",
        "deliveryDate": "Thu Apr 23 2020 01:57:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"
    }
```

and the response I get states "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String \"Thu Apr 23 2020 01:57:47 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)\". This is what the form component looks like in my React file

```
class Add extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {   
        id: '',
        customer: '',
        destination: '',
        driver: '',
        deliveryDate: new Date()
        } 
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    onChange = deliveryDate => 
    this.setState({ deliveryDate })


    submitHandler = e => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add', this.state)
    }

    render() {
        const { customer, destination, driver, deliveryDate} = this.state
        return (
        <div className="add-form">
            <Form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group >
                    <Form.Label>Customer</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" name="customer" value = {customer} onChange= {this.handleChange} />
                    <Form.Label>Destination</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text"  name="destination" value= {destination}  onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <Form.Label>Driver</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text"  name="driver" value= {driver} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <Form.Label>Delivery Date</Form.Label>
                    <Calendar   name="date" value= {deliveryDate} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="success" type="submit" className="add-button1" href={"/"}>Add Load</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to format the date so that my Post requests actually get through? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using sending the data in UTC as string and parsing it in the back-end to the object type you want?

Comment: "Thu Apr 23 2020 01:57:47 GMT-0500", give a try only with this. The TimeZone text in () might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try sending in the datetime as epoch time, and then convert it to a date object in the backend..

Frontend like

```
submitHandler = e => {
    const { deliveryDate } = this.state;
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add', { ...this.state, deliveryDate: deliveryDate ? deliveryDate.getTime() : null  })
}
```

And your backend like..

```
    Long deliveryDate = abc.getDeliveryDate();
    Date deliveryDateObj = new Date(deliveryDate);
```